# Fixing c-fill-paragraph with comments in Emacs 23.2.1

Tags: emacs

I just upgraded to emacs 23.2.1 when I finally upgraded to ubuntu 10.10, but the first thing I noticed is that c-fill-paragraph (M-q) doesnt work nicely with comments anymore or at least do not work the way they did in emacs 23.1.? that I had before the upgrade.

The main issue is that if I have a commented line such as

```
//This is a long comment to illustrate an issue I have with emacs lorem ipsum
```

and then do fill-paragraph (M-q) afterwards, I get

```
//This is a long comment to illustrate an issue I have with
emacs lorem ipsum
```

whereas I should get

```
//This is a long comment to illustrate an issue I have with
//emacs lorem ipsum
```

I've killed my .emacs file to try and narrow down where the issue is popping up, but this still pops up even in vanilla emacs.

Comment: I just tested in Gnu Emacs 23.2.1, and I am not seeing a problem.  Are you sure in the right editing mode (i.e. c-mode, c++-mode)?

Comment: boo, I suspected as much.  ok that's good to know.  I thought it might be one of the modes I was using (cc-mode, nxhtml) but I guess I didnt get to as vanilla a state as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/ccffbea322b1b9d7) with a patch that can be used if recompiling emacs from scratch.  Turns out it's a bug in cc-mode that hopefully is fixed in the next version of emacs.

Another somewhat easier solution is to simply use `fill-paragraph` rather than `c-fill-paragraph`.

EDIT: and from [the php mode emacs page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PhpMode), it appears you have to manually apply the patch since the line #'s don't line up with the current emacs source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `longlines-mode` on by any chance?  Auto-fill and longlines don't mix well (but I have a hack for it):

```
(defadvice fill-paragraph (around fill-paragraph-ignore-longlines act)
  "Ignore longlines-mode when calling fill-paragraph."
  (let ((restore-ll-mode nil))
    (when (boundp 'longlines-mode)
      (setq restore-ll-mode longlines-mode))
    (when restore-ll-mode
      (longlines-mode 0))
    ad-do-it
    (when restore-ll-mode
      (longlines-mode t))))
```

In order to get to plain-vanilla emacs, type `emacs -q --no-site-init` at the shell prompt.

Comment: I dont use longlines-mode, and even with emacs q --no-site-file (--no-site-init isnt recognized) it still doesnt comment correctly.